Tracing data consumption
I need to implement distributed-tracing for our applications hosted on OpenShift. We have many projects, some with a user count < 100 and some > 1000 and greater.
We do need to estimate how much storage, i.e., S3 in our case, this would require.
Can anyone give me some advice / tip on how I can reliably estimate data consumption for tracing? I actually could not find sufficient information on the web.

There is a lot of missing information in your post that is crucial to answering this question.
What technology will you use? (dynatrace/jaeger/zipkin/...)
How long do you plan to store the data?
What will your trace data look like - how much contextual data will be written to the traces/spans?
Best thing you can do (in my opinion) is kick off a PoC on a subset of apps/services with a low sample rate and measure the data ingestion. Then you can expand the PoC to include additional services or increase the sample rate, and continue to monitor.
